# How to Read two XML files and return List(of object)?

Tags: vb.net

I have two xml files. I have to read them and return as a List( Of object).

Here is my function.

```
 Public Function GetData(ByVal name As String, ByVal city As String) As List(Of Object)
        'Return Nothing
 End Function
```

Thanks,

NJ

Comment: Why List(Of Object) ?  What type of data is in the xml files?

Answer (score 0):

You may change return type into "Object" and then make it type cast to "List (Of Object)" , though it's ugly